# how to understand the agrument return the variables

Tags: java

I find the similar code in the c# language, now I still do not understand it in java ,the code is below

```
public class TaskItemAnswerObject {
    private Integer examPaperId;
    private Integer examPaperAnswerId;
    private Integer status;

    public TaskItemAnswerObject(){

    }

    public TaskItemAnswerObject(Integer examPaperId, Integer examPaperAnswerId, Integer status) {
        this.examPaperId = examPaperId;
        this.examPaperAnswerId = examPaperAnswerId;
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

so why we fist define the integer variable examPaperId,then why we repeat do such thing ,like "this.examPaperId= examPaperId",it is strange for me.should I use other method to do that parameter transfer? Or any benefit to do such thing?

Comment: You'd better read some Java book to learn the syntax (constructor, class, 
field) than asking here; also try researching first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three places where the name `examPaperId` is referenced.  The purpose of each line is as follows:

```
private Integer examPaperId;
```

declares that the `TaskItemAnswerObject` class contains an instance variable name `examPaperId` of type `Integer`.

```
public TaskItemAnswerObject(Integer examPaperId, Integer examPaperAnswerId, Integer status) {
```

declares a constructor for the `TaskItemAnswerObject` object that takes a parameter of type `Integer`, named `examPaperId`, as its first parameter.

```
this.examPaperId = examPaperId;
```

is executed when the constructor mentioned above is called.  It takes the incoming parameter named `examPaperId` and assigns it to the instance variable named `examPaperId` on the instance of the `TaskItemAnswerObject` class that is being constructed.

There are other languages that can do all of this in less code.  Kotlin, specifically, can do all of this in a single line of code.  But Java's syntax is what it is.  This is just the way all of this works in Java.